# Carrying variables from one query to another to create chained nodes with cypher

Tags: neo4j, cypher

This may be a stupid way to do this. I want to create a chain of nodes, possibly thousands of them in the following form:

```
(n0)-[r0]->(n1)-[r1]->(n2)...
```

I have programatically generated cypher which looks something like this:

```
MERGE (n0:Person)-[r0:RelType]->(n1:Person)
WITH n1 MERGE (n1:Person)-[r1:RelType]->(n2:Person)
WITH n2 MERGE (n2:Person)-[r2:RelType]->(n3:Person)
WITH n3 MERGE (n3:Person)-[r3:RelType]->(n4:Person)
WITH n4 MERGE (n4:Person)-[r4:RelType]->(n5:Person)
...
```

I then copy pasted above queries in neo4j web console and ran, but it gave following error:

```
Can't create node `n1` with labels or properties here. The variable is already declared in this context
```

I understand (or I dont?) we cannot use `MERGE` inside `WITH` . Also I know we can bulk import nodes, relationships from CSV using `Neo4jImport`. ***But I was just curious if we can generate a bunch of cyphers to copy paste them in neo4j web console and create the desired graph.***

Answer (score 2):

If the only thing you want is to create a long chain of nodes, you can just unwind a range :

```
CREATE INDEX ON :Person(id)
```

---

```
UNWIND range(1,100) AS i
MERGE (p:Person {id: i-1})
MERGE (p2:Person {id: i})
MERGE (p)-[:RelType]->(p2)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

@Luanne is on the right track, but I think this is what you want:

```
CREATE (n1:Person)
WITH n1 AS n CREATE (n)-[:RelType]->(n1:Person)
WITH n1 AS n CREATE (n)-[:RelType]->(n1:Person)
WITH n1 AS n CREATE (n)-[:RelType]->(n1:Person)
WITH n1 AS n CREATE (n)-[:RelType]->(n1:Person)

(and so on...)
```

Except for the first line, all other lines are identical. I used `CREATE` because I don't think you want to use `MERGE` at all, since I believe you are trying to create totally new data. You can use `MERGE` instead if I am wrong about that.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should remove the label when merging the relationship on the node n1 supplied via the WITH

```
MERGE (n0:Person)-[r0:RelType]->(n1:Person)
WITH n1 MERGE (n1)-[r1:RelType]->(n2:Person)
WITH n2 MERGE (n2)-[r2:RelType]->(n3:Person)
WITH n3 MERGE (n3)-[r3:RelType]->(n4:Person)
WITH n4 MERGE (n4)-[r4:RelType]->(n5:Person)
```

(untested)